# Can you set a type for a function in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want for a function to implement a certain type of interface, to have a certain type of signature. The same way you would implement an object.

Say I have an interface like this:

```
interface IStrategyOptionsWithRequest {
    usernameField?: string | undefined;
    passwordField?: string | undefined;
    session?: boolean | undefined;
    passReqToCallback: true;
}
```

I can quickly determine that `passReqToCallBack` is required if I give the type `IStrategyOptionsWithRequest` to the instance that I'm creating.

```
let localStrategyOptions : IStrategyOptionsWithRequest  = {
    passReqToCallback: true
}
```

Say I have another interface like this:

```
interface VerifyFunctionWithRequest {
    (
        req: express.Request,
        username: string,
        password: string,
        done: (error: any, user?: any, options?: IVerifyOptions) => void
    ): void;
}
```

How can I now create a function that is of type `VerifyFunctionWithRequest`? This would be useful so that I'm certain that the function I'm creating has the correct signature.

I did try

```
function verify: VerifyFunctionWithRequest (){
    
}
```

which gives me:

```
'(' expected.
```

Is this even a thing or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Edit: Clarifying that I'm interested that the IDE would give me a linting error in the case I'm not implementing the function correctly.

Comment: use type instead of interface

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function type like this:

```
const verify: VerifyFunctionWithRequest =
  function (req, username, password, done) {

  };
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  The problem with this approach is that there isn't any code linting happening. If I remove all of the parameters from the function, I don't get any errors.

Comment: `If I remove all of the parameters from the function, I don't get any errors.` That's by design. Typescript will make sure that when the function gets called, all the values in the type must get passed in. But it doesn't force you to actually **use** those values. If your function has no code using the values, that's no problem. And since it's legal to not use them, typescript isn't going to force you to write them out in the argument list. If you choose to write the arguments out and give them types, typescript will make sure the types match.

Comment: [See this documentation page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions) for how typescript compares function types. They give an example of code like this: `items.forEach((item) => console.log(item));` That code is legal, even though the function actually receives 3 arguments (item, index, and array).

Comment: @sander: Nicholas Tower explained it perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use a builder function that builds your requested function for you, in that case you are guaranteed to have a specific layout. Here is an example of this:

```js
type VerifyFunctionWithRequest = (
    req: unknown,
    username: string,
    password: string,
    done: (error: any, user?: any, options?: unknown) => void
) => void;

const verify = ((): VerifyFunctionWithRequest => 
    (req, username, password, done) => {
        // Your "verify" function goes here
    }
)()

// Use verify as usual
verify(req, "username", "password", () => console.log("Done"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem with this approach is that I can not use the interface that has been provided to me by a library and I would have to re-define the interface as a "type".